# Android Dialog and AsyncTask Caused UI to Freeze

Tags: java, multithreading, android-asynctask, android

So, in my Dialog, I have a button which starts an Asynctask downloader to get some file from my server; and that works just fine. However, I want to dismiss my current Dialog and display the ProgressDialog on button clicked. How would I approach this problem?

At the moment, if I click on the button (an element inside my Dialog) the whole UI get froze while the downloader downloading the file from the server. Once the downloader finished its task then the progress dialog will then get shown.

My code looks something like this

```
MainActivity{

    Dialog dialog;
    ProgressDialog progress;

    onCreate(){
        dialog = new Dialog(this);
        progress = new ProgressDialog(this);
        dialog.setContentView(Some View Resource With My Button);
        someMethod();
        dialog.show();
    }

    someMethod(){
        Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(resource of button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            onClick(){
                dialog.dismiss();
                progress.show();
                new DownloaderAsyncTask(progress).execute().get();
            }

                    //go to another activity when download finished

        });
    }

    private class DownloaderAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        ProgressDialog progress;

        DownloaderAsyncTask(ProgressDialog progress){
            this.progress = progress;
        }

        doInBackGround(){
            //Downloading
        }

        onPostExecute(){
            //Kill connection
            this.progress.dismiss();
        }

    }

}
```

Thanks. Please let me know if you guys need any additional information.

Comment: There is no error. The UI got froze because it was waiting for the downloader to finish. Once the downloader finished, everything works just fine. However, I want my current dialog to be dismissed and progressDialog to be shown as soon as the button is clicked.

Comment: Do not call `get()`. see the answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
new DownloaderAsyncTask(progress).execute().get();
```

I really have no idea why `AsyncTask` has the `get()` method - it basically turns the asynchronous process into a synchronous one because it will block and wait for a result. That's the reason the UI freezes.

If you want to wait for the downloader to finish and then do something else, that's what `onPostExecute(...)` is for.

Answer (score 2):

You UI thread is frozen because you called `get()`. Do not do that. Instead launch your `AsyncTask` and make your `onPostExecute()` call method containing the code you wanted to be executed when download ended, like this (more/less):

```
someMethod() {
        Button button = (Button) dialog.findViewById(resource of button);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener(){

            onClick(){
                dialog.dismiss();
                progress.show();
                new DownloaderAsyncTask().execute();
            }
        });

private void downloaderFinished() {
    this.progress.dismiss();
    /// go to next activity.
}

private class DownloaderAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void>{

        doInBackGround(){
            //Downloading
        }

        onPostExecute(){
            //Kill connection
            downloaderFinished();
        }
    }
```

That's how it shall be done as `async` stands for, well, asynchronous so calling `get()` kills all the benefits.